# How works these methods in controllers, assets in js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this example
And i wanna understand what it is " ||= " in this method? How it works?

***First segment***

```
 def current_user
            @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
          end
```

also, i dont know what does (function()) mean in Ruby on rails. Its not simple function(), why is it inside brackets?

***Second example***

```
(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: ||= means in your case that if @current_user does not exist then look it up using the session[:user_id] if that exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `||=` is equivalent to

```
@current_user || @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

Meaning, if `@current_user` is nil or false set `@current_user` to be the value of `User.find(session[:user_id])` in the case there is a `session[:user_id]`

The second example is not Ruby on Rails, but JavaScript. It's the so called “Immediately Invoked Function Expressions" and it's wrapped with parenthesis so that you can call it with a specific parameter, in your case `this`. So that the `this` inside the IIFE has the context of where that IIFF was called.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about other operators, it will be easier to see what this `memoize` does.

When we do `@var += 1`, we are basically saying `@var = @var + 1`. That's the same for other operators:

`@var -= 1` => `@var = @var - 1`
`@var ||= 1` => `@var = @var || 1`

That means that, if @var is set, it does not change its value, but if @var is nil, it will set its value with the one you provided. It works like a cache, if there is a value, use it, but if there is not, set the new value and use it.

Try this on the terminal:

```
[1] pry(main)> var ||= 10
=> 10
[2] pry(main)> var ||= 20
=> 10
[3] pry(main)> var = nil
=> nil
[4] pry(main)> var ||= 20
=> 20
```